# Uninstall other apps from an application in react native

Tags: react-native, expo

Are there any packages or libraries through which we can uninstall other applications by browsing inside another application.

Let's say I have an application named "Skype" and want to uninstall the application "Facebook" while I am inside "Skype" by a single button click. Is it possible to do that?
How ever it is possible to do in android native but is that do able in react native?

Comment: you should first know how to execute commands to android system so you can do such things

Comment: Considered, but I need to know libraries which can do that?

Comment: @rishavkumar do you have link on how to do it on Android?